# OpenCV not detecting faces from Kinect

Tags: c++, opencv, face-detection, openni

I'm trying to detect faces using a kinect with the code below. OpenCV's detectMultiScale() correctly detects faces when I use my computer's camera, but it doesn't seem to be working with the images from the kinect.

```
Device device;
VideoFrameRef colorFrame;
VideoStream ColorStream;
Mat colorImage, grayScaleFrame;

colorStream.create(device, SENSOR_COLOR );
colorStream.start();


while (1){
    colorStream.readFrame(&colorFrame);
    const RGB888Pixel *imageBuffer = (const RGB888Pixel*)colorFrame.getData();
    colorImage.create(colorFrame.getHeight(), colorFrame.getWidth(), CV_8UC3);
    memcpy(colorImage.data, imageBuffer, 3 * colorFrame.getHeight() * colorFrame.getWidth() * sizeof(uint8_t));

    //face detection
    blur(colorImage, colorImage, Size(2, 2), Point(-1, -1), BORDER_DEFAULT);
    cvtColor(colorImage, grayScaleFrame, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    equalizeHist(grayScaleFrame, grayScaleFrame);
    classifier.detectMultiScale(grayScaleFrame, faces, 1.1, 3, CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE,  Size(30, 30) );
}
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: which driver are you using for Kinect? Freenect or OpenNI?
Check if your image coming from Kinect is BGR or RGB.

Comment: @blackibiza - I'm working with OpenNI. I tried both CV_BGR2GRAY and CV_RGB2GRAY and the program is still not detecting any faces

Comment: Have you tried saving the image that comes from kinect to check if everything is as you expected? after try to run the opencv algorithm in this single image to check if the algorithm is working well with this images...

Comment: @Stralo consider that retrieving a frame from Kinect is different from the procedure for a normal camera.
With OpenNI (I hope you are using the 1.5.x with avin2 patch) you must first call grab() and then retrieve() on VideoCapture.

Comment: @blackibiza - Was my mistake, guys. Sorry. I the haarcascade file was in the folder containing my source and not where the executable was, and I just realized that because the classifier.load() function doesn't throw any error. I'll delete the post

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you follow these steps for grabbing a frame with Kinect/OpenNI (1.5.4.0+):

```
cv::Mat rgb_image, depth_map;
cv::VideoCapture device.open(CV_CAP_OPENNI);
//set RGB-Depth mapping
device.set(CV_CAP_OPENNI_DEPTH_GENERATOR_REGISTRATION, 1.0);

while(1)
{
  device.grab();
  device.retrieve(rgb_image, CV_CAP_OPENNI_BGR_IMAGE);
  device.retrieve(depth_map, CV_CAP_OPENNI_DEPTH_MAP);
}
```

Comment: I'm working with Opencv 2.4 and OpenNI2. I think the code above doesn't work for OpenNI2 : main.cpp:341:14: error: ‘class openni::Device’ has no member named ‘grab’
main.cpp:342:14: error: ‘class openni::Device’ has no member named ‘retrieve’. thanks though!

Comment: OpenNI2 doesn't work with Kinect, unless you are on Windows, you have Windows SDK + OpenKinect cross patch for OpenNI2.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a11ff6d9-7fbe-4636-8ff0-92d6220ac3f8/fyi-openni-2-is-available-uses-ms-kinect-sdk-drivers-when-using-kinect-sensor?forum=kinectsdk

On Linux, no chances.

Comment: I'm working on a linux machine with OpenNI2 and Kinect,and everything is working fine.